# Unable to select text inside a tag

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, copy

I have the following sample code:

```
<a href="http://example.com">
   <p>...</p>
   <img src="" />
</a>
```

Need to be able to copy text from `p` tag. The problem that `p` and `img` inside `a` and I can't select it.

I need exactly this HTML structure, as user should be able to copy link from that block.
How can I do that?

Answer (score -1):

Well, a link can be copied if you start dragging your mouse from the outside of it.

If you want a more natural feel, you can provide your users with a **Copy This Link** button, and have JavaScript copy it for him.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can append a text input after the link, just for the first click.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/eKFnB/)**

HTML:

```
<a href="http://example.com" class="selectable">
   <p>...</p>
   <img src="" />
</a>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.selectable').one('click',function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    var el = $(this);
    var txt = el.find('p').text();
    $('<input type="text" value="'+txt+'" style="display:block">')
            .insertAfter(el)
            .select();
});​
```